# Why left and right margins don't change in the top of my e-mail's HTML?

Tags: html, css, margin, html-email, padding

I am struggling with changing the margins of the text in the top of my e-mail's HTML. I need my text to take more space on the left so it is not squeezed in the top right corner and doesn't run for 4 lines. Here's the code:

```css
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
 <meta content="width=320, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" name="viewport" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <style type="text/css">/* Mobile-specific Styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) { 
table[class=w0], td[class=w0] { width: 0 !important; }
table[class=w10], td[class=w10], img[class=w10] { width:10px !important; }
table[class=w15], td[class=w15], img[class=w15] { width:5px !important; }
table[class=w30], td[class=w30], img[class=w30] { width:10px !important; }
table[class=w60], td[class=w60], img[class=w60] { width:10px !important; }
table[class=w125], td[class=w125], img[class=w125] { width:80px !important; }
table[class=w130], td[class=w130], img[class=w130] { width:55px !important; }
table[class=w140], td[class=w140], img[class=w140] { width:90px !important; }
table[class=w160], td[class=w160], img[class=w160] { width:180px !important; }
table[class=w170], td[class=w170], img[class=w170] { width:100px !important; }
table[class=w180], td[class=w180], img[class=w180] { width:80px !important; }
table[class=w195], td[class=w195], img[class=w195] { width:80px !important; }
table[class=w220], td[class=w220], img[class=w220] { width:80px !important; }
table[class=w240], td[class=w240], img[class=w240] { width:180px !important; }
table[class=w255], td[class=w255], img[class=w255] { width:185px !important; }
table[class=w275], td[class=w275], img[class=w275] { width:135px !important; }
table[class=w280], td[class=w280], img[class=w280] { width:135px !important; }
table[class=w300], td[class=w300], img[class=w300] { width:140px !important; }
table[class=w325], td[class=w325], img[class=w325] { width:95px !important; }
table[class=w360], td[class=w360], img[class=w360] { width:140px !important; }
table[class=w410], td[class=w410], img[class=w410] { width:180px !important; }
table[class=w470], td[class=w470], img[class=w470] { width:200px !important; }
table[class=w580], td[class=w580], img[class=w580] { width:280px !important; }
table[class=w640], td[class=w640], img[class=w640] { width:300px !important; }
table[class*=hide], td[class*=hide], img[class*=hide], p[class*=hide], span[class*=hide] { display:none !important; }
table[class=h0], td[class=h0] { height: 0 !important; }
p[class=footer-content-left] { text-align: center !important; }
#headline p { font-size: 30px !important; }
.article-content, #left-sidebar{ -webkit-text-size-adjust: 90% !important; -ms-text-size-adjust: 90% !important; }
.header-content, .footer-content-left {-webkit-text-size-adjust: 80% !important; -ms-text-size-adjust: 80% !important;}
#customHeaderImage { height: auto;width: 140px !important; line-height: 100%;}
.banner {width:100%;}
.banner-content {width:50px; padding-top:0 !important; padding-bottom: 0 !important; display:none;}
.banner-cont-sm {display:block !important;}
.hidden-sm { display:none;}
.display-sm {display:block !important;}
table {border-spacing:0; border-color:none;}
 } 
/* Client-specific Styles */
.display-sm {display:none;}
#outlook a { padding: 0; } /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" button. */
body { width: 100% !important; }
.ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }
.ExternalClass { width: 100%; display:block !important; } /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
/* Reset Styles */
/* Add 100px so mobile switch bar doesn't cover street address. */
body { background-color: #dedede; margin: 0; padding: 0; color: #464646 }
img { outline: none; text-decoration: none; display: block;}
br, strong br, b br, em br, i br { line-height:100%; }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { line-height: 100% !important; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a { color: blue !important; }
h1 a:active, h2 a:active,  h3 a:active, h4 a:active, h5 a:active, h6 a:active { color: red !important; }
/* Preferably not the same color as the normal header link color.  There is limited support for psuedo classes in email clients, this was added just for good measure. */
h1 a:visited, h2 a:visited,  h3 a:visited, h4 a:visited, h5 a:visited, h6 a:visited { color: purple !important; }
/* Preferably not the same color as the normal header link color. There is limited support for psuedo classes in email clients, this was added just for good measure. */  
table td, table tr { border-collapse: collapse; }
.yshortcuts, .yshortcuts a, .yshortcuts a:link,.yshortcuts a:visited, .yshortcuts a:hover, .yshortcuts a span {
color: black; text-decoration: none !important; border-bottom: none !important; background: none !important;
} /* Body text color for the New Yahoo.  This example sets the font of Yahoo's Shortcuts to black. */
/* This most probably won't work in all email clients. Don't include code blocks in email. */
code {
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}
#background-table { background-color: #dedede; }
/* Webkit Elements */
#top-bar { border-radius:6px 6px 0px 0px; -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px; -webkit-border-radius:6px 6px 0px 0px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; background-color: #fff; color: #ededed; }
#top-bar a { font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;}
#footer { border-radius:0px 0px 6px 6px; -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px; -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 6px 6px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
/* Fonts and Content */
body, td { font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; }
.header-content, .footer-content-left, .footer-content-right { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none; }
/* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes on header and footer. */
.header-content { font-size: 12px; color: #000000; }
.header-content a { font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; }
#headline p { color: #444444; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; font-size: 36px; text-align: center; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:30px; }
#headline p a { color: #444444; text-decoration: none; }
.article-title { font-size: 18px; line-height:24px; color: #464646; font-weight:bold; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:18px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; }
.article-title a { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
.article-title.with-meta {margin-bottom: 0;}
.article-meta { font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px; color: #ccc; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0;}
.article-content { font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #444444; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 18px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; }
.article-content a { color: #20C5BA; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; }
.article-content img { max-width: 100% }
.article-content ol, .article-content ul { margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:18px; margin-left:19px; padding:0; }
.article-content li { font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #444444; }
.article-content li a { color: #20C5BA; text-decoration:underline; }
.article-content p {margin-bottom: 15px;}
.footer-content-left { font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; color: #ededed; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
.footer-content-left a { color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
.footer-content-right { font-size: 11px; line-height: 16px; color: #ededed; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
.footer-content-right a { color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
#footer { color: #ededed; }
#footer a { color: #392f46; text-decoration: none; }
#permission-reminder { white-space: normal; }
#street-address { color: #b0b0b0; white-space: normal; }
 </style>
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style _tmplitem="266" >
.article-content ol, .article-content ul {
   margin: 0 0 0 24px;
   padding: 0;
   list-style-position: inside;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="background-table" width="100%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="center" style="background-color:#dadada">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w640" style="margin:0 10px;" width="640">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td class="w640" height="20" width="640"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="w640" width="640">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w640" id="top-bar" width="640">
       <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:#fff">
         <td class="w15" height="20" width="15"></td>
         <td align="left" class="w325" valign="middle" width="350">
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w325" width="350">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="w325" height="8" width="350"></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>

         <div class="header-content"></div>

         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w325" width="350">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="w325" height="8" width="350"></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </td>
         <td class="w30" width="30"></td>
         <td align="right" class="w255" valign="middle" width="255">
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w255" width="255">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="w255" height="8" width="255"></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>
            <p style="text-align: right;color: #276CA8;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-size:10px; font-weight: bold"><em>We are a charity that provides emergency care across Australia. By signining up, you can win $50,000 and help us in saving over 5,000 lives a year. Can&#39;t see this e-mail?<br />
            <a data-id="577666557" data-title="View it online!" href="{{ocx_mirror_page}}" style="color:#276CA8;font-weight: bold"><u>View it online!</u></a></em></p>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For HTML mail, use inline styles only, as most mail clients will strip out everything in the header, css style links included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width` in `table` are always tricky. a `td` width not only dependent on the width applied to it but also the width of `body` and other `td`s which are sibling to them. So you have to adjust the other `td`s and inner `table` widths to give more space to to the text.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="background-table" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="background-color:#dadada">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w640" style="margin:0 10px;" width="640">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w640" height="20" width="640"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w640" width="640">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w640" id="top-bar" width="640">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr style="background-color:#fff">
                                    <td class="w15" height="20" width="15"></td>
                                    <td align="left" class="w325" valign="middle" width="150">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w325" width="50">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="w325" height="8" width="50"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                    <div class="header-content"></div>

                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w325" width="50">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="w325" height="8" width="350"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w30" width="30"></td>
                                    <td align="right" class="w255" valign="middle" width="1554">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w255" width="555">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="w255" height="8" width="255"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                <p style="text-align: right;color: #276CA8;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-size:10px; font-weight: bold"><em>We are a charity that provides emergency care across Australia. By signining up, you can win $50,000 and help us in saving over 5,000 lives a year. Can't see this e-mail?<br>
                                                <a data-id="577666557" data-title="View it online!" href="{{ocx_mirror_page}}" style="color:#276CA8;font-weight: bold"><u>View it online!</u></a></em></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you don't need a special layout you can remove all `width`s. All `td` will automatically adjust according to it's containers.

I've roughly changed the other width and `td`s and `table`s. And if you are creating an email template it's good to inline all styles. Most of the email clients ignore styles in headers.

Comment: Thanks, this does the job!!

Comment: Yes, I did, but it reverts back to 0, giving the following message: Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.